# How to install mod_ssl for Apache httpd?

Tags: apache, ssl, httpd.conf, webmin, virtualmin

Ok

So I installed Apache `httpd` a while ago and have recently come back to it to try setup SSL and get it serving several different tomcat servers.

At the moment I have two completely separate Tomcat instances serving up to slightly different versions (one for dev and one for demo say) my web app to two different ports:

- `example.com:8081`
- `example.com:8082`

I've successfully (back in Jan) used `mod_jk` to get `httpd` to serve those same Tomcat instances to `http://www.example.com:8090/dev` and `http://www.example.com:8090/demo`  (8090 cos I've got another app running on 8080 via Jetty at this stage) using the following code in `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel debug

<VirtualHost *:8090>
    JkMount /devd* tomcatDev
    JkMount /demo* tomcatDemo
</VirtualHost>
```

What I'm not trying to do is enable SSL.

I've added the following to `httpd.conf`:

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    JkMount /dev* tomcatDev
    JkMount /demo* tomcatDemo
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/httpd/conf/localhost.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/httpd/conf/keystore.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to restart Apache with `apachectl restart` (yes after shutting down that other app I mentioned so it doesn't toy with https connections) I continuously get the error:

> Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration. httpd not running, trying to start

I've looked in the `httpd/modules` dir and indeed there is no `mod_ssl`, only `mod_jk.so` and `httpd.exp`.

I've tried using yum to install `mod_ssl`, it says its already installed. Indeed I can locate `mod_ssl.so` in `/usr/lib/httpd/modules` but this is NOT the path to where I've installed `httpd` which is `/opt/httpd` and in fact `/usr/lib/httpd` contains nothing but the `modules` dir.

Can anyone tell me how to install `mod_ssl` properly for my installed location of `httpd` so I can get past this error?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Are any other `LoadModule` commands referencing modules in the `/usr/lib/httpd/modules` folder? If so, you should be fine just adding `LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so` to your conf file.

Otherwise, you'll want to copy the `mod_ssl.so` file to whatever directory the other modules are being loaded from and reference it there.

Comment: In my Apache installation `mod_ssl.so` was outright missing. Turns out its separate from the base installation and was under the package `mod_ssl` in the yum package manger. Downloaded using `yum install mod_ssl` then it appeared in the `modules` folder.

Comment: I found, after compiling my own apache 2 that mod_ssl.so was missing. need to compile it again, from scratch.

Comment: @ug_ thanks, I confirm that after installing the module it included the module and also added a `ssl.conf` file that has the needed configurations.

Answer (score 126):

I found I needed to enable the SSL module in Apache (obviously prefix commands with `sudo` if you are not running as root):

```
a2enmod ssl
```

then restart Apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

More details of SSL in Apache for Ubuntu / Debian [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/ssl-apache2-debian-ubuntu).

Comment: Which distribution OS are u using?

Comment: @Naga `a2enmod` is from the Debian world.

Answer (score 35):

Try installing `mod_ssl` using following command:

```
yum install mod_ssl
```

and then reload and restart your Apache server using following commands:

```
systemctl reload httpd.service
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

This should work for most of the cases.

Comment: If you install Apache from source, then yum will not be able to detect it. Instead it will install a duplicate (outdated) version of Apache, and put mod_ssl.so in *that* Apache's module files.

Answer (score 6):

I used:

```
sudo yum install mod24_ssl
```

and it worked in my Amazon Linux AMI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is still of interest and if things have changed ever since the thread has been posted, but the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` on my system says:

> Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
> directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
> global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
> respectively.
>
> They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
> respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
> helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
> their respective man pages for detailed information.

And on my system the modules are installed in /usr/lib/apache2/modules.
I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.