# Check whether SSL is enabled in an installed Apache web server

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-ssl

I am working on setting up a web server, in this case Apache 2.2.14. We already have an installed version. I have imported the module mod-ssl and when i restart Apache, i get the following error

> mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol 'X509_free

I checked that the possible reason may be that when the server was configured --enable-ssl wasn't set (https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=8620). I need to check whether ssl was enabled on this server before I can ask the admins to reinstall the same.

Is there a way to check the same and confirm that ssl was enabled while configuring the server?

This question provides how to enable ssl using the a2enmod command but this command is not available in the version i am using.

[How to install mod_ssl for Apache httpd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257974/how-to-install-mod-ssl-for-apache-httpd)

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: That would depend on exactly how your apache was compiled. e.g. if it's for a linux distro, then ssl will probably have been compiled as a module and would show no sign of ssl being available unless the ssl module package was installed

Comment: Thanks @Marc B for your inputs. The machine is RedHat 4.1.2. So you mean to say that there is no way to figure out whether ssl was configured while compiling?

Comment: it probably was compiled, but may be in a separate rpm that you don't have installed.