# sudo service httpd restart gives an error or ssl.conf

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf

I want to restart httpd aws ec2 linux. I write following command in terminal.

```
  sudo service httpd restart
```

But it gives me following error.

```
Starting httpd: AH00526: Syntax error on line 18 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
Invalid command 'SSLPassPhraseDialog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
                                                       [FAILED]




Starting httpd: AH00526: Syntax error on line 23 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
Invalid command 'SSLSessionCache', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
                                                       [FAILED]
```

If i comment the line then it will show below error.

```
Starting httpd: AH00526: Syntax error on line 24 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
Invalid command 'SSLSessionCacheTimeout', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I dont think so that each time i have to comment the lines.
Currently, i dont need ssl.conf. 
So i dont want to call it when i am going to restart httpd.
how can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: how did you comment out ? Using `#` at the begin of line 24.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan:- Yes i used # at the begin on line 24

Comment: The second error log is the same the first error log, have you done comment out `#` before `SSLSessionCacheTimeout` line

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan: updated

Comment: would help if you can show /etc/http/httpd.conf - generally if you don't need ssl.conf, rename it ssl.backup

Comment: I guess mod_ssl is disable,try to enable it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257974/how-to-install-mod-ssl-for-apache-httpd

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan:- I dont need  mod_ssl and i dont want to install it.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri:- it is simple file. there is nothing related to the ssl.conf

Comment: Move `ssl.conf` file to other folder, for example : `mv ssl.conf /root/` , then restart httpd again.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan:- Ok

Answer (score 2):

When a module that provides certain Directives is not loaded Apache config check will complain about not "knowing" about them as you see in the errors you get.

You don't have mod_ssl loaded and that's why HTTPD giving you those config errors. Either load mod_ssl or make sure no mod_ssl directives are present (uncomment, delete, do not include ssl.conf, the choice is yours).

Answer (score 2):

In my Centos 7 system, installing  `mod_ssl` and  `python2-certbot-apache` packages fixed the issue

`sudo yum install epel-release`

`sudo yum install  mod_ssl  python2-certbot-apache`

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the httpd and php again.
May be your config is broken.
I hope it works.